# Spring WS : Start Endpoint at startup

Tags: spring, spring-ws, endpoint

I'm using Spring WS to create WebService following by the link here

http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-web-services-tutorial.html

And dynamic wsdl following by the setting here in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I would like to ask is that possible to create Endpoint bean on startup time rather than waiting client to call on the endpoint url ?

Comment: `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` you currently disabled auto-start with your value of 0.

Comment: I've tried with 1, no luck as I implement @PostConstruct to start all services used by Endpoint, but nothing happen until client call to address like "http://localhost..../endpoint"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I set annotation @Lazy(false), Endpoint bean will be initialised only when client call to the web service address which I believe it's the normal behaviour. I'll use workaround solution by putting "curl" script to call url on deployment to make sure that every beans are initialised before  making any request